# Function to find position of variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Learning python and trying to return the row of where the string "A" is in the list, but its returning none in the visualizer. Its supposed to return the row index 1. Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?
Code I have so far:

```
locale3 = [['.',    '.',    '.',    'e'], ['A', 'A',    '.',    'e'], ['.', '.',    '.',    'e'], ['.', 'X',    'X',    'X'], ['.', '.',    '.',    '.'], ['.', 'y',    'Z',    'Z']]
def row_locale(locale):
    for i in range(len(locale)):
        if locale[i] == "A":
            return len(locale)
row_locale(locale3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each element of `locale` is an array of strings. When you do

```
if locale[i] == "A":
```

You compare such array to a single string "A", which is always false. If you want to find a locale that *has* "A", change it to this:

```
if "A" in locale[i]:
```

EDIT: You also return the length of the matching locale. You probably want to return `i` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Yeah, returning i is what I needed.